# json not parsing

Tags: ios, json, ios6

I have the code below for json which is parsed by NSURLconnection and  NSJSONSerialization :

```
{
  "JSonArray" : [
    {
      "JsonLog" : {
        "msg" : "test",
        "sno" : "1",
        "user" : "test1"
      }
    },
    {
      "JsonLog" : {
        "msg" : "test",
        "sno" : "2",
        "user" : "test2"
      }
    },
    {
      "JsonLog" : {
        "msg" : "test",
        "sno" : "3",
        "user" : "test3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Code I have used :

```
NSError *requestError = NULL;

NSDictionary *allData=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webdata options:0 error:&requestError];


if (requestError){
    //An error occurred.
    NSLog(@"error is : %@",requestError);
}

if (! allData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", requestError);
} else {
    NSLog(@" data is : %@",allData) ;
}



NSArray *arrayOfEntry=[allData objectForKey:@"JSonArray"];

for (NSDictionary *diction in arrayOfEntry) {

    NSDictionary *title=[diction objectForKey:@"JsonLog"] ;

    NSString *label=[title objectForKey:@"sno"];

    [array addObject:label];

}
```

The response for  **NSLog(@" data is : %@",allData)**  is :

```
{
    JSonArray =     (
                {
            JsonLog =             {
                msg = "test";
                "sno" = 1;
                user = test1;
            };
        },
                {
            JsonLog =             {
               msg = "test";
                "sno" = 2;
                user = test2;
            };
        },
                {
            JsonLog =             {
                msg = "test";
                "sno" = 3;
                user = test3;
            };
        }
    );
}
```

Where am I going wrong and how do I set it right? Is there something I am missing ?

Any Advice will help e a great deal.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What's your problem? The JSON is parsed correctly.

Comment: maybe he's confused about the quote signs in the NSLog output?

Comment: Yes Sir.The code looks fine to me too but I am stuck ,also Mr.Dautermann is correct I am also confused about the quotes while debugging .But the code is exactly like mentioned above .PLease try it out and let me know why its not working.I tried to paste the array in tableview but not working.Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems regarding the code nor the behavior, since the JSON is parsed correctly.

Update: I have tried compiling and running your code, and after `NSLog()`ging the resulting `array` variable, it displayed

```
(
    1,
    2,
    3
)
```

So the error is certainly somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your time but I am not getting the value .It looks perfect to me too .In Log the quotes are missing .But Apart from that I am stuck.The code is exactly as mentioned above.

Comment: @JamesPatrick That's the description of the `NSDictionary` you get. It means that the JSON has been successfully parsed to a dictionary.

Comment: @JamesPatrick Also, what does "I am not getting the value" mean?

Comment: Ok So if it has successfully parsed,then how do I get the value of "sno" from every array from above .I mean I am not getting the "sno".If you can re-write the above code that would be great.

Comment: @JamesPatrick The code you have seems fine too. Are you sure you don't have a typo, a capital/small letter mismatch, etc. when using the keys of the dictionaries? Are you allocating-initializing `array`?

Comment: I have **array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];** in viewDidLoad.